# How to switch between multiple templateUrls in $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

I spent many hours today to search for a solution of switching template url in angularjs using $routeProvider, but it seem their solutions didn't work in my case.
The requirement in user story requires the same url: /home for different user roles (normal and auditor), after they login. Below is current code:

```
$routeProvider
            .when(
                '/home',
                {
                    templateUrl: 'views/pages/home/home-page-view.html',
                    controller: 'HomePageController',
                    resolve: {
                        loggedin: checkLoggedin
                    }
                })
            .when(
                '/auditor-home',
                {
                    templateUrl: 'views/pages/auditor-home/auditor-home-page-view.html',
                    controller: 'AuditorHomePageController',
                    resolve: {
                        loggedin: checkLoggedin
                    }
                }
            ).otherwise(
            {
                redirectTo: '/home'
            }
        );
```

Now I don't want to use route /auditor-home, use only one route : /home for both auditor user and normal user. Remember that I have to call API (in function **checkLoggedin**) to get user is auditor or normal.
Below is the code of function  **checkLoggedin** if you need :

```
checkLoggedin = function ($q, $window, AuthenticationService, UserModel, UserService, OrganisationService, HomePageService, $location) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            AuthenticationService.authenticate().then(
                function successHandler() {
                    return UserService.user();
                },
                function errorHandler(errorResponse) {
                    deferred.reject(errorResponse);
                }
            ).then(
                function successHandler(successResponse) {
                    UserModel.user = (successResponse && successResponse.data) ? successResponse.data : {};
                    return HomePageService.checkKpiTestMode();
                },
                function errorHandler(errorResponse) {
                    deferred.reject(errorResponse);
                }
            ).then(
                function successHandler(successResponse) {
                    var testModeInfo = successResponse.data;
                    isAuditor = UserModel.isAuditCompanyAdmin() || UserModel.isAuditAdmin();
                    isSiteAdmin = UserModel.isSiteAdmin();
                    isCompanyAdmin = UserModel.isCompanyAdmin();
                    if (!UserModel.isCompanyAdmin() && !UserModel.isSiteAdmin() && !UserModel.isAuditCompanyAdmin() && !UserModel.isAuditAdmin()) {
                        deferred.reject();
                    } else if (testModeInfo && testModeInfo.testMode === true && testModeInfo.authorisedUsersForTesting && testModeInfo.authorisedUsersForTesting.indexOf(UserModel.user.userCode) === -1) {
                        deferred.reject();
                    } else if (UserModel.user.organisationCode) {
                        if (isAuditor) {
                            $location.path('auditor-home');
                        }
                        return OrganisationService.getMy();
                    } else {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    }
                },
                function errorHandler(errorResponse) {
                    deferred.reject(errorResponse);
                }
            ).then(
                function successHandler(successResponse) {
                    UserModel.organisationName = successResponse && successResponse.data ?
                        successResponse.data.organisationName : null;
                    deferred.resolve();
                },
                function errorHandler(errorResponse) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
            );

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the approach mentioned below:

```
when('/home',
            {
                template: '<div ng-include="getTemplate()"></div>',
                controller: 'HomePageController',
                resolve: {
                    loggedin: checkLoggedin
                }
            })
...
```

and then in your controller you can set the template based on the return value of checkLoggedin function.

```
 $scope.getTemplate = function(){
        if (checkLoggedIn) {
           return 'a.tpl.html';
        } else {
           return 'b.tpl.html';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comment from @arbghl , below is my answer: 
*main.js* :

```
$routeProvider
            .when(
                '/home',
                {
                    template: '<div ng-include="getTemplate()"></div>',
                    controller: 'DefaultPageController',
                    resolve: {
                        loggedin: checkLoggedin
                    }
                })
            .otherwise(
            {
                redirectTo: '/home'
            }
     );
```

*default-page-controller.js* :

```
angular.module(
'DefaultPageControllerModule', []).controller(
    'DefaultPageController', [
        '$scope',
        'UserModel',
        function ($scope, UserModel) {
            $scope.getTemplate = function () {
                var isAuditor = UserModel.isAuditCompanyAdmin() || UserModel.isAuditAdmin();
                if (isAuditor) {
                    return 'views/pages/auditor-home/auditor-home-page-view.html';
                } else {
                    return 'views/pages/home/home-page-view.html';
                }
            };
        }
    ]
);
```